# Python unable to import GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run a Python code with GDAL library. I've created the environment and installed GDAL and GeoPandas but the Python won't import the GDAL for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are the installed libraries in the environment.
[image]

GDAL is clearly installed. I am running the code in same environment in vscode and I am still getting `No module named 'gdal'` error:

```
import os
import gdal
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

[image]

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

Comment: Is this a Windows environment? Is your GDAL the same bitedness as your python (i.e. 64/64 or 32/32)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using gdal 3.6 and trying to use an older style of gdal syntax that was deprecated in gdal 1.7 (Jan 2010) and removed in 3.1 (May 2020).

The correct import is:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

From the [documentation](https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html#usage) (note the bolded text):

> Imports
>
> There are five major modules that are included with the GDAL Python
> bindings.:
>
> ```
> from osgeo import gdal
> from osgeo import ogr
> from osgeo import osr
> from osgeo import gdal_array
> from osgeo import gdalconst
> ```
>
> Additionally, there are five compatibility modules that are included
> but provide notices to state that they are deprecated and will be
> going away. If you are using GDAL 1.7 bindings, you should update your
> imports to utilize the usage above, **but the following will work
> until GDAL 3.1**.
>
> ```
> import gdal
> etc...
> ```